# ion-searchbar in Ionic 4 throws icons not found errors on browser console

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionicons

I'm trying to implement `ion-searchbar` in my **Ionic 4** app.

```
  <ion-toolbar mode="ios">
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-searchbar></ion-searchbar>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </ion-toolbar>
```

but, it throws below error in the browser console. I was not able to display clear text icon in the searchbar.

```
Cannot find "/dist/ionicons/svg/ios-close-circle.svg" in ionicons@5.0.0
```

Please note I have these two script files in the `index.html`

```
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.0.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule="" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.0.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
```

Could anyone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Ionic 4, you can access Ionicons without including the script references. It should also be noted that with the release of [Ionic 5](https://ionicframework.com/blog/announcing-ionic-5/), Ionicons styling received an upgrade and previous references to `md` or `ios` styling have been removed in favor of three distinct style choices for each icon (`outline`, `filled`, and `sharp`).

With the `ion-searchbar` component, the `clear-icon` property [automatically defaults to the `close-circle` icon](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/searchbar#properties), but you can change this by setting the `clear-icon` attribute:

```
<ion-searchbar clear-icon="close-sharp"></ion-searchbar>
```

For reference, if you want to include an icon separately of the `ion-searchbar`, you can do it like so:

```
<ion-icon name="close-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
```

where the `outline` portion of the name can be replaced with either `filled` or `sharp` depending on your style preference. Here's the list of all updated icons and their names: https://ionicons.com/

Comment: Perfect, this is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Since ionic2 there are no external links are required for the ionic in-built feature so you can remove these links from index.html.

Or you can download ionic 4 ionic-conference-app [demo template] for more reference.